# Apply filter for groupby aggregate function in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

How to apply filter for groupby aggregate function in Pandas?

I have DataFrame

```
data = {'Fruit':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'kivi', 'kivi', 'kivi'],
              'Y_or_N': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 
              'A_or_B': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
              'Number': [3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I want for each fruit group sum Number values in 3 columns: (1) all values,  (2) where 'Y_or_N'=='Y', (3) where 'A_or_B'=='A'.

I have tried the following:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Fruit']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Y_or_N'] == 'Y' ].agg(sum_Y=('Number', 'sum')))
```

This works, but only for 1 column. Is there a more efficient way to apply different filters for different columns and aggregate functions? Without making 3 df and then merging them together.

Desired output:

| Fruit | sum_all | sum_Y | sum_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 14 | 9 | 8 |
| kivi | 13 | 4 | 11 |

Answer (score 3):

I would first rework the columns, then aggregate:

```
(df.assign(sum_Y=lambda d: d['Number'].where(d['Y_or_N'].eq('Y')),
           sum_A=lambda d: d['Number'].where(d['A_or_B'].eq('A')),
          )
   .rename(columns={'Number': 'sum_all'})
   .groupby('Fruit', as_index=False)[['sum_all', 'sum_Y', 'sum_A']].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
   Fruit  sum_all  sum_Y  sum_A
0  apple       14    9.0    8.0
1   kivi       13    4.0   11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's are three ways you can do it:

**Way #1:**

```py
res = ( df
    .Number.pipe(lambda s: pd.DataFrame({
        'Fruit':df.Fruit, 
        'sum_all':s, 
        'sum_Y':s[df.Y_or_N.eq('Y')], 
        'sum_A':s[df.A_or_B.eq('A')]}))
    .groupby('Fruit', as_index=False).sum().convert_dtypes() )
```

**Way #2:**

```py
res = pd.DataFrame({
    'sum_all':df.groupby('Fruit').Number.sum(),
    'sum_Y':df[df.Y_or_N.eq('Y')].groupby('Fruit').Number.sum(),
    'sum_A':df[df.A_or_B.eq('A')].groupby('Fruit').Number.sum()}).reset_index()
```

**Way #3**: This is a variation on the excellent answer by @mozway with the following tweaks:

- factors out the common `Number` column access into a Series we pipe into a lambda
- uses `convert_dtypes` to get back to int for the sums of filtered columns where NaN caused an upcast to float

```py
res = (df.Number.pipe(lambda s: df
    .assign(sum_Y=lambda d: s[d.Y_or_N.eq('Y')], sum_A=lambda d: s[d.A_or_B.eq('A')]))
    .rename(columns={'Number': 'sum_all'})
    .groupby('Fruit', as_index=False).sum().convert_dtypes()
)
```

Output:

```
   Fruit  sum_all  sum_Y  sum_A
0  apple       14      9      8
1   kivi       13      4     11
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Fruit':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'kivi', 'kivi', 'kivi'],
              'Y_or_N': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 
              'A_or_B': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
              'Number': [3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


r1 = df.groupby(['Fruit'])['Number'].sum()
r2 = df.groupby(['Fruit']).apply(lambda d: d[d['Y_or_N'].eq('Y')]['Number'].sum())
r3 = df.groupby(['Fruit']).apply(lambda d: d[d['A_or_B'].eq('A')]['Number'].sum())

r = pd.concat([r1, r2, r3], axis=1).set_axis(['Sum_All', 'Sum_Y', 'Sum_A'], axis='columns')

print(r)
```

```
       Sum_All  Sum_Y  Sum_A
Fruit                       
apple       14      9      8
kivi        13      4     11
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
res_df = df.pivot(index='Fruit', columns=['Y_or_N', 'A_or_B'], values='Number')
res_df = pd.concat([res_df.sum(1).to_frame('sum_all'),
                    res_df.xs('Y', axis=1).sum(1).to_frame('sum_Y'),
                    res_df.xs('A', level=1, axis=1).sum(1).to_frame('sum_A')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
   Fruit  sum_all  sum_Y  sum_A
0  apple     14.0    9.0    8.0
1   kivi     13.0    4.0   11.0
```